# How do I create a post request to get the authentication token for oauth2 authorization in RestAssured?

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, rest-assured

I am trying to post a request to "get new access token". username, password and grant_type are mandatory which I specified in params. The objective is to get the authentication token to be used in subsequent post requests. Below is the RestAssured code. I am getting `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` error through RestAssured, but have been able to generate token by using these details in PostMan. What mistake I may have been making? Thanks in advance!

```
String response = given() .params("username", username,"password", password, "grant_type", password).when().post("/authorization/oAuth2/Token") .then().statusCode(200).extract().asString();
```

Comment: Can you show how you are passing these parameter in Postman. Maybe then I can help.

Comment: @rohit.jaryal : In postman, on clicking "Get New Access Token" button, when the new screen opens, I am providing the following details- Token Name, Grant Type, Access Token URL, Username, Password, Client Authentication and clicking on "Request Token" button.